# How to handle new attribute added to directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Here is my directive:

```
return {
       restrict: 'E',

       scope: {
           showBorder: '='
       },
       link: function (scope, element) {

           alert(scope.showBorder);
```

Here is my directive written inside HTML:

```
<my-directive showBorder="true"></my-directive>
```

But alert saying - scope.showBorder is undefined?
What did I miss here?

Answer (score 2):

Atribute names are camelcase.

So if you define `showBorder` in the scope you need to reference it with `show-border`in your directive html.

ex:

```
<my-directive show-border="true"></my-directive>
```